# C library implementing TCP but not IP

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, embedded

I am working on a radio controlled embedded device (32-bit ARM, <1M memory). The radio provides an unreliable link supporting small packets of a fixed size. I would like to implement a reliable byte stream protocol on top of this link.

There are many implementations of the TCP/IP stack together, but what about a standalone TCP implementation with no dependencies? I'm imagining some interface like

```
typedef int (*send_fn)(char const *, int);
typedef int (*recv_fn)(char *, int);
void setup_tcp(send_fn send, recv_fn recv, int max_packet_len);
```

where I give the library function pointers to send and receive unreliable packets, and it calls my functions but deals with forming headers, SYN/ACK, etc. itself. Alternatively, these functions could be specified at compile time instead of by function pointers. (The desired API is not exact, just trying to get the idea across.)

Does such a library exist?

I do not actually need all features of TCP - for example "urgent" data. Since the radio provides very small packets, I will also want to reduce the size of the sequence number, fewer available ports, etc. So I will make a "reduced" TCP protocol. But I think the optimal way to do this would be to start with a working TCP implementation and remove features.

Comment: That would not be TCP. You are free to create your own transport protocol, or use one other than TCP or UDP. Many things use UDP and add a few TCP-like features to the application protocol.

Comment: please read my last paragraph closely, I stated that I think it would be easier to start with a working TCP implementation and remove features rather than implement something very similar to TCP from scratch.

Comment: I don't know of a library to use, but https://superuser.com/questions/449703/must-tcp-use-ip has some good information about the possibility.

Comment: I saw that, but it would not be TCP, and it would not inter-operate with anything else. In any case, asking for such a thing is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand that TCP assumes some routing layer is available to deliver datagrams, but is it not possible to replace the IP layer with something different, like the pigeons or morse code mentioned in the "Must TCP use IP?" question, or my radio link?

Comment: @japreiss, I have withdrawn the comment you responded to.  However, I am nevertheless inclined to think that building a *TCP-inspired* protocol from scratch will be a more fruitful approach for you than tearing up an existing implementation.

Comment: I'd think you're better off keeping IP and using your new link as a replacement for layer 2. There is a lot more support and "prior art" for this. For example, it would be very straightforward to implement TCP and IP atop your new link layer using an existing library such as lwIP (https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/). Plus then it wouldn't be difficult to add a network driver implementing your protocol to linux, say, as a test bed. You can then use ping, netcat, and other existing utilities to communicate with your new system.

Comment: Note your "unreliable packet protocol" would replace Ethernet, not TCP.